# jcifs.smb.SmbException: The system cannot find the file specified?

Tags: java, smb

While running the below code i am getting the exception

> jcifs.smb.SmbException: The system cannot find the file specified

**Code:**

```
public void m1(String b) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method**strong text** stub

        BufferedReader br=null;
        String urlToBackUpFile = "smb://" +b +"/" + "c$/Program Files/Office/Config/OfficeSyncData.ini";
        String cp="smb://" +b +"/" + "c$/Program Files/Office/Config/OfficeSyncData.txt";
        System.out.println("smb folder of source file" + urlToBackUpFile);
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "usrname", "passwd");


          SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(cp, auth);
          SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream( dir );
         // br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));


          System.out.println(dir.getDate());
          SmbFile dest = new SmbFile (urlToBackUpFile,auth);
          //count.copyTo(dest);
          dir.copyTo(dest);

    }
```

How do i resolve?.

Comment: Is "b" in the specified path?

Comment: What is the value of `b` and which line does the exception refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Without the entire stack trace I cannot be completely sure, but you may need to specify in the path the escape space character.

Try this:

```
String urlToBackUpFile = "smb://" +b +"/" + "c$/Program\\ Files/Office/Config/OfficeSyncData.ini";
```

And make sure that if "b" contains a space you do the same.

**EDITED: also to try: can you point the path to a location that doesn't contain any spaces? that would prove if the space syntax is the source of your problems...**

Comment: You'd need at least two ` \ ` if you want to escape it that way, i.e. `program\\ files`. Not saying it will help though.

Comment: sorry, edited the code to include the double '\' . Maybe worth a try anyway as the shell language of linux terminals (even when emulated in windows) need the space escaping